# How can I automatically start my SQL Server upon debugging my website?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, automation, projects-and-solutions

I don't want SQL Server to start upon boot, thus I only want it to start when I'm actively developing. Thus, I would like an action in my solution or project file that launches SQL Server too when I press F5 or when I open the solution.

How can I accomplish this automatically in Visual Studio?

If you have an idea how I can stop the SQL Server when I close the solution or VS, feel free to share that as well although I don't mind that SQL Server runs after I'm done developing; I just don't want it to launch when I don't want it to. Its idle performance is fine...

Comment: If you're on Windows Vista or newer, you can set it to "delayed start", which will lessen the impact on your boot times, if that's what's bothering you...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that directly when launching your solution, but you can integrate startup / shutdown in visual studio, see this: [How to start/stop local SQL Server service directly from Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161305/how-to-start-stop-local-sql-server-service-directly-from-visual-studio)

Another trick would be to just make a shortcut on desktop with "NET START MSSQLSERVER" (given that it is a default instance). You could just click this before launching visual studio, or even change visual studio shortcut to start sql server first then launch devenv.