# Cannot find nor start any MSSQL server by any tool: Server Management 2014/2016, Configuration Manager 2014/2016, Visual Studio, powershell etc

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a database script which I would like to execute:

```
USE [Zza]

/*** Drop Order Tables Script Date: Thu Jun 06 2013 18:37:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time) ***/
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[OrderItemOption]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OrderItemOption] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_OrderItemOption_ProductOption]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OrderItemOption] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_OrderItemOption_OrderItem]
DROP TABLE [dbo].[OrderItemOption]
END
GO....
```

When I open SQL Server Management Studio 2014 I have no registered servers nor I can register any.

[image]

In Visual Studio 2015 I have these servers visible:

[image]

How can I detect or create server in SQL Server Management Studio 2014 so I can execute my database creation script and make my connection string will work?

This is my connection string, based on a WCF Jumpstart tutorial:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ZzaDbContext" connectionString="server=.;database=Zza;trusted_connection=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

**EDIT:**
I also tried that solution:

[image]

also tried that approach: [How to start/stop local SQL Server service directly from Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161305/how-to-start-stop-local-sql-server-service-directly-from-visual-studio/1161561#1161561) but then when I try to start the server I get: Name of service is not correct: NET HELPMSG 2185.

**EDIT 2**
I installed SQL Server Management Studio 2016. There are no servers available:

[image]

and when I try to open **Configuration Manager 2016** I get this:

[image]

also after installation of MSSMS 2016 one new server appeared in Visual Studio 2015:

[image]

Comment: is the sql server browser service running on the machine where sql server is running ?

Comment: Just type SERVER\INSTANCE in *Server name* field. Also try pushing button to expand this window and choose *Browse for more*

Comment: @gofr1 I get the same error as always: `cannot connect to SERVER\INSTANCE` there was network related error 26.

Comment: @GuidoG I did not find such thing on my computer https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/hh510203(v=sql.110).aspx how can I run it? I installed Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise with ALL packages, there should sth like this ; (

Comment: @Yoda check in SQL Server Configuration manager if there is tcp/ip enabled for your instances

Comment: @gofr1 I think this is it and it's enabled: https://s18.postimg.org/sd8mekro9/abc.png but I want to run my server locally so I am not sure if that matters.

Comment: @Yoda it is enabled! The next one to check if `SQL Server Browser` is running. In same Configuration Manager.

Comment: @gofr1 I can't see any option to start/stop or check its state. This Configuration Manager looks like it has no options to modify anything. I right-clicked everything clickable.

Comment: @Yoda The SQL Server Browser Service has nothing to do with visual studio, it is part of SQL Server. You should check if its running on the same machine as your SQL Server is running even you have sql server and vs on the same machine. You can check it in services.msc or in SQL Sever Configuration Manager as gofr suggested

Comment: @GuidoG In msservices I got only: SQL Server VSS Writer. I also tried that approach: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1161561/1123020 but then when I try to start the server I get: `Name of service is not correct: NET HELPMSG 2185.` I just can't start any server or find any server on my computer via any software except visual studio : /

Comment: @GuidoG I also tried what I've show in the edit to the original post.

Comment: @gofr1 There are no servers in browse for more section in MSSMS but when I typed `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` (this is the server found in visual studio SQL Object Explorer visible on last image) it connected to it, but still it isn't server that is detected by MSSMS automatically nor started by MSSMS or Configuration Manager, but a "magic server" created or detected by Visual Studio. I updated the question substantially, to show all my efforts.

Comment: Oh its a local DB. Have you installed the SQL Server Native Client? It cannot be found using Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server. You need SQL Server Native Client 11.0 (or 12.0) and in this case I dont think you still need the SQL Server Browser service

Comment: @GuidoG "SQL Server Native Client (SNAC) is not supported beyond SQL Server 2012. Avoid using SNAC in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it. The Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server provides native connectivity from Windows to Microsoft SQL Server and Microsoft Azure SQL Database."

Whenever I try to install Native Client 2012 it says newer version already exists on this machine. As I stated I installed mssms 2016.

Comment: try this: create a txt file anywhere on your disk and rename its extension to .udl Now doubleclick on it and you will get a screen that helps you build a connenctionstring. On the first tab of this screen what are your options for connection to SQL Server ?